# Get Position from SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, position, simplecursoradapter

Is there a way to do this? My specific purpose is that I am trying to populate a label from an edittext within my list that is populated by a simplecursoradapter. When I gather the information from the cursor is only gives me the value from the most recent item in the list.

Example:

```
        lbs = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainLbs);
    lbs.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
            if(!popState){
                parentActivity.showPopup(v, mView, getId, String.valueOf(getLbs));
                Log.i("Current ID", "");
            }
            setPopState();
            return true;
        }   
    });
```

I'm trying to pass the value from the database to a method in my activity from within my custom simplecursoradapter (String.valueOf(getLbs)) which since i'm gathering this information by clicking on an object in the listview I thought it would automatically use the data from the specific list item. Is there a way I can get the list item position and then use info from the database based on the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be such a simple answer and I can't believe i've spent so much time trying to figure it out. Because I was collecting the value within an inside method (an onclicklistener) I needed to make my variable final, it was declared at the beginning of the class so it could be used throughout, and because of this I wasn't getting an exception, but I needed to make it final before it would pass the correct value for whatever reason.

So I guess if you bind your views within a customcursoradapter you can collect values for each individual listitem without knowing the position, it automatically knows this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending `ListActivity`, then you can override L[istActivity.onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29).  The second argument passed into that function is the position in the list, which is the same as the position in your `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: I am not extending ListActivity. I need to extend Activity so this unfortunately isn't an option. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why can't you extend ListActivity instead of Activity?

Comment: Because I need to override onCreate, onPause, onDestroy etc etc. The list resides in my main view.

Comment: That is exactly what ListActivity gives you.  ListActivity extends Activity, so you inherit all of the same methods.  Take a look at the JavaDoc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: I figured out a simpler solution without having to extend ListActivity, but that is good to know the next time I need it. Thanks elevine.